# Issues with push notification while reinstalling application

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am facing a strange issue in my application. On a new device while installing the application push notifications are working fine but reinstalling the application I am receiving no notifications. Is it issue from the API or do I have to do something while terminating the application?

The code for registering device :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
        SHARED_MGR.deviceToken = deviceTokenString
        let str = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString as String
        let characterSetForDeviceID: CharacterSet = CharacterSet( charactersIn: "-" )
        deviceID = ( str as NSString )
            .trimmingCharacters( in: characterSetForDeviceID )
            .replacingOccurrences( of: " ", with: "" ) as String

        SHARED_MGR.DeviceIDStr = deviceID
        createDevice()
    }
```

Code for requestauthorization :

```
if( UIDevice.current.systemVersion >= "10.0"){
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.delegate = self
            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge], completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
                if granted{
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

                } else {
                    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
                        print(status)
                    }
                }
            })
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }


    }
    else {
        let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
        let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you update push token on each launch..

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Device Token is updating on each new launch to the server.

If you are using static Device Token for push notification, this might be the issue.

You are not getting the Push Notification on the new launch.

Because device token will always change on the new Install.

Comment: I am making api call each time the app is launched, the thing which I observe is that the delegate method : didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is called multiple times . Is this the issue ?

Comment: Please share the code you are using for Registering Push Notifications.

Comment: You shared the delegate method, I need the code used for registering Push Notification.
Which you written in didfinishlaunchingwithoptions function.

Comment: Not done anything with push notifications in didfinishlaunchingwithoptions

Comment: Where did you write the code to register for push notifications, 

Please see below code for references :

        // iOS 10 support
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {  
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:
        [.badge, .alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in }
         application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
         }

Comment: I have requested authorization in a view controller which is the root controller

Comment: Please share that code, which you write in ViewController or Rootviewcontroller